# Is there an easier way to type apostrophes on the Droid X keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, motorola-droid-x

Is there an easier way to type apostrophes on the Droid X keyboard?

Two issues --

1. I press and hold the period key, which brings up the little pallet of punctuation.  But the apostrophe is inexplicably all the way over on the left.  Can I move this closer to the right, where my thumb is while clicking and holding the period key?  It's the most common character I use from this pallet.
2. Alternately, can I somehow get an apostrophe on the overhead menu that appears when you type a space?  This is the place where auto-correct goes, but when you type a space, it becomes a comma, exclamation point, question mark, etc.  How can I get an apostrophe in this list?

Answer (score 1):

You can 'cook up' (create) your own keyboard thanks to an awsome android dev. (That way you can have the apostrophe wherever you want :-)

See here: http://www.gimpsta.com/themer/

It has also had a blog review here: [create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for-android-devices/)